# load balancer requests fail unexpectedly sometimes on AWS in spring boot application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, okhttp, amazon-elb

**Update**
I get the following response quite often:
response code 502 and headers [awselb/2.0] 
and sometimes:
response code 500 and headers null

I assume this is amazon's elastic load balancer messing with us?

**Original question**

We have servers running in different regions on AWS and once in a while they make GET request to each other to check their status. We also have external monitoring services checking the same calls.

Sometimes (too often) we get a Http 3XX response, but we know from both logs and other monitoring services that all servers are running fine. We've also seen similar behavior for servers on the same network.

I'm wondering if our http client is poorly configured or there is a bug somewhere. See the code below for the service we use to send our requests. Any suggestions? We use com.squareup.okhttp3 version 3.14.2.

(Apologies for posting an issue without isolating the cause better, just hoping that someone else experienced this before and has a solution.)

```java
import okhttp3.*;

@Service
public class HttpClientService {
    public static final MediaType JSON_MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    private OkHttpClient client = null;
    private long httpClientTimeoutSeconds = 10;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(httpClientTimeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(20, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                .build();
    }

    public Response get(String url) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                .header("content-type", "application/json");
        Request request = requestBuilder
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .build();
        return client.newCall(request).execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the 3xx.response include a 'server' header? That might tell you which middlebox is interfering.

Comment: I'll check that! If there are other headers to watch out for, let me know.

Comment: You could also add a `Server` header to your own server and use that to have confirmation about which process is returning the 3xx response.

Comment: See updated question. Based on the server header it doesn't reach the server

Comment: Looks like the ELB is standing in for your server, presumably because your server is unhealthy or slow.

Answer (score 0):

as it seems so the requested url results in some "Redirection".

just an idea:
Maybe the requested url produces some redirection to https?

For sure I would check the requested url and why it returns some Redirection http code.

Comment: The URL is https directly, but good point. I'll try to see if the 'server' header is set as pointed out above.